TextContext DataRow missing definition after loss of files
I accidentally deletes a bunch of files from my hard drive with a reckless powershell script.
Before this happened, I had a working project with MSTest that used the TestContext class to provide access to test data using DataRow.
I had to reinstall Visual Studio as a result but now whenever I add the MSTest NuGet package to a project, it does not add all of the expected definitions to the TestContext class. Namely the DataRow property. There are others missing as well.
the error thrown are CS0117 and CS1061, which both just state that there is no definition in the TestContext class for DataRow, which is true.

My question is, how is this possible!?! Do I need to just reinstall Windows and start from scratch?
I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling VS as well as .NET SDKs with no change. I don't understand what would cause numerous definitions to no longer be added... any help is appreciated...
I confirmed that the the project is targeting the correct version of .NET (i've tried 4.8 and 5.0, no change).
I don't have this on other machines when loading the project.

Does this answer your question? 'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow'
